# what is the best way to join series with additional symbol and left out none and nan value?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I got a series like this

```
0             stand and on the top of the m
1                        be aware of the p
2                           in the night o
3                                       tt
4                                       锉
```

Here is my code

```
x1=x.str.split(pat='/').str[0].copy()
x2=x1.str.split(expand=True).copy()
x2['combined']=x2[x2.columns].apply(lambda row: '+'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
x2['combined']
```

the result of x2 is

```
0             stand+and+on+the+top+of+the+m
1             be+aware+of+the+p+None+None+None
2             in+the+night+o+None+None+None+None
3             tt+None+None+None+None+None+None+None
4             Nan+Nan+Nan+Nan+Nan+Nan+Nan+Nan
```

The outcome I want is

```
0             stand+and+on+the+top+of+the+m
1             be+aware+of+the+p
2             in+the+night+o
3             tt
4
```

what should I do?

Comment: So need replace spaces by `+` only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the spacer:

```
x.str.replace('\s+', '+', regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    stand+and+on+the+top+of+the+m
1                be+aware+of+the+p
2                   in+the+night+o
3                               tt
4                                锉
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
x['combined']=x.str.split(pat='/').str[0].str.split().str.join('+')
```